How to Implement Filtering and Sorting with React and Next.js in an API-Driven Application?
I'm building a React application with Next.js where I need to fetch cards from an API and display them based on user-selected filters. Specifically, I want to fetch cards initially and then filter them based on the user's selected location. Here's the structure of my components and API routes:
page.js
import { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Title from "./Title";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import CardsArea from "./CardsArea";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default function Home() {
  const [filterOption, setFilterOption] = useState({});
  const [sortOption, setSortOption] = useState("");

  const handleFilterChange = (filter) => {
    setFilterOption(filter);
  };

  const handleSortChange = (sort) => {
    setSortOption(sort);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Title />
      <SearchBar onFilter={handleFilterChange} onSort={handleSortChange} />
      <CardsArea filterOption={filterOption} sortOption={sortOption} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
CardsArea.js
javascript
Copy code
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default function CardsArea({ filterOption, sortOption }) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialCards();
  }, [filterOption, sortOption]); // Reload cards when filter or sort options change

  const loadInitialCards = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      // Fetch cards with filter and sort options
      const response = await fetchCards(page, filterOption, sortOption);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (data.length === 0) {
        setHasMore(false);
      } else {
        setCards(data);
        setPage(page + 1);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading initial cards:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const fetchCards = async (pageNum, filterOption, sortOption) => {
    // Construct API URL with filter and sort parameters
    const url = `/api/cards?page=${pageNum}&location=${filterOption.location}&month=${filterOption.month}&sort=${sortOption}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response;
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-auto w-full flex bg-white flex-col justify-center pt-5">
      <div className="flex justify-center flex-col mx-auto">
        {cards.map((card, index) => (
          <Card key={index} {...card} />
        ))}
        {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {!loading && !hasMore && <p>End</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

route.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { query } from "../../../lib/db";

export const GET = async (req) => {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const location = searchParams.get('location');
  const month = searchParams.get('month');
  const sort = searchParams.get('sort');
  
  try {
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM card";
    let conditions = [];

    if (location) {
      conditions.push(`location = '${location}'`);
    }
    if (month) {
      conditions.push(`MONTH(departDate) = '${month}'`);
    }
    if (conditions.length > 0) {
      sqlQuery += " WHERE " + conditions.join(" AND ");
    }
    if (sort) {
      sqlQuery += ` ORDER BY ${sort}`;
    }

    const results = await query({ query: sqlQuery });

    return NextResponse.json(results);
  } catch (e) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: e.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
};

SearchBar.js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function SearchBar({ onFilter, onSort }) {
  const [locationFilter, setLocationFilter] = useState("");
  const [monthFilter, setMonthFilter] = useState("");
  const [sortOption, setSortOption] = useState("");

  const handleFilterChange = () => {
    onFilter({ location: locationFilter, month: monthFilter });
  };

  const handleSortChange = () => {
    onSort(sortOption);
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto border rounded-md border-black dark:bg-white bg-white shadow-lg p-2 flex flex-col sm:flex-row">
      <div className="flex sm:border-none border-b border-black">
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-center sm:justify-start">
          <select
            id="location"
            value={locationFilter}
            onChange={(e) => setLocationFilter(e.target.value)}
            className="text-black w-full sm:w-64"
          >
            <option value="">Departure Location</option>
            <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
            <option value="Aurangabad">Aurangabad</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-center mt-0 sm:mt-0">
          <input
            id="month"
            type="month"
            value={monthFilter}
            onChange={(e) => setMonthFilter(e.target.value)}
            className="text-black"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-center sm:justify-end mt-0 sm:mt-0">
          <select
            id="sort"
            value={sortOption}
            onChange={(e) => setSortOption(e.target.value)}
            className="text-black dark:text-black w-[174px] lg:pt-3 pt-6 sm:w-48"
          >
            <option value="">Sort</option>
            <option value="price ASC">Low to High</option>
            <option value="price DESC">High to Low</option>
            <option value="ratings DESC">Ratings</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-center sm:justify-end mt-2 sm:mt-0">
          <input className="w-full sm:w-auto" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center mt-2 sm:mt-0">
          <button
            className="sm:w-9 w-full sm:block sm:pt-0 pt-2 sm:pr-0 pr-2 mt-1 flex sm:justify-normal justify-center h-8 rounded bg-gray-900"
            onClick={handleFilterChange}
          >
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-4 ml-3" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
              <path fill="#ffffff" d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40 122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3 0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0 208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 352a144 144 0 1 0 0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


How can i achieve it ?
i tried few ways but it didnt worked

use an array to perform filtering and sorting operations locally. you can
try this method,
fetch data as normal way like this,
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);


const fetchCards = async () => {
  // Construct API URL with filter and sort parameters
  const url = '/api/cards';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  setLoading(true);

try {
  // Fetch cards with filter and sort options
  
  const data = await response.json();
  let dataarray = [] 

  if (data.length === 0) {
    setHasMore(false);
  } else {
    data_array.push(data)
    setCards(data_array);
    setPage(page + 1);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error loading initial cards:", error);
} finally {
  setLoading(false);
}

};
use one useEffect for fetching data from the api
useEffect(() => {
  fetchCards();

},[]
and use another useEffect for filtering and sorting data like this,
and also use another array for set the Filtered data Sorted data to the Frontend
const [filtereddata, setFilteredData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {

   if(data.length > 0){
     const { location = '', month = '' } = filterOption
     let dataresult = [...cards]
   

     if(location){
       dataresult = dataresult.filter((item) => 
       item.location.toLowerCase().includes(location.toLowerCase()))

     if(month){
       
       dataresult = dataresult.filter((item) => 
       item.month.toLowerCase().includes(month.toLowerCase()))

     
     if(sort == 'abc'){
       dataresult.sort((a,b) => 
       // do your sort operations

      setFilteredData(dataresult)

   }else{
     setFilteredData(cards)
   }

}, [filterOption, sortOption, cards])

